# Combinations of single elements from respective sublists

Tags: python, list, recursion, sublist

If I have the list `my_list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']`, how can I create a list of all possible tuples where each tuple contains a single element from each sublist? For example:

`('a', 'e')` is valid
`('a', 'b')` is invalid
`('b', 'c')` is valid
`('c', 'd')` is invalid

Importantly, `my_list` can contain any number of elements (sublists) and each sublist can be of any length. I tried to get a recursive generator off the ground, but it's not quite there.

I’d like to try and use recursion rather than itertools.

The logic was to iterate through 2 sublists at a time, and store those results as input to the next sublist's expansion.

```
def foil(lis=l):
    if len(lis) == 2:
        for x in l[0]:
            for y in l[1]:
                yield x + y
    else:
        for p in foil(l[:-1]):
            yield p


for i in foil():
    print(i)
```

However, this obviously only works for the `len(my_list) == 2`. It also needs to work with, say, `my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]` which would return:

`('a', 'b', 'c')`
`('a', 'b', 'd')`

Cheers!

Comment: itertools product

Comment: Updates, I was initially vague

Answer (score 3):

Use `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools

my_list = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e']]
print(list(itertools.product(*my_list)))
# [('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'e'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'd'), ('b', 'e')]

my_list = [['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'd']]
print(list(itertools.product(*my_list)))
#[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd')]
```